# Problems about Hashmap

Tags: java

Here is my code, that's my first time using HashMap. 
I don't really understand why the value of key "a" is changed after I assign a value to key "d". Seems like the value of key "a" is re-written each time I assign a value to anther key.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.*;

class BowlingSystem {

    static HashMap<String, BowlingSystem> bs=new HashMap();//abbreviate for Bowling System
    public String Name;
    public int no_game;//same as above
    public String[] date;
    public int total_score=0;
    public String last_date;
    public int last_score;
    public int[] score;

    public BowlingSystem(String Name_i, String[] date_i, int[] score_i){
        score=score_i;
        Name=Name_i;
        date=date_i;
    }

    public void register (BowlingSystem information){
        bs.put(information.Name,information);
    }

    public void out(String input){
        if (bs.containsKey(input)) {
            BowlingSystem information=(BowlingSystem)bs.get(input);
            no_game=information.date.length-1;
            last_date=information.date[no_game];
            last_score=information.score[no_game];

            for(int i=1;i<=no_game;i++){
                total_score=total_score+score[i];
            }

            double avg=(double)total_score/no_game;
            System.out.println("Name is "+information.Name+"\n");
            System.out.println("Number of games is "+no_game+"\n");
            System.out.println("Average score of all of the games is "+avg+"\n");
            System.out.println("The score of the last game is "+last_score+"\n");
            System.out.println("The date of the last game is "+information.date[no_game]+"\n");
        }
    }
}

    public class Homework06 {
        public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        int[] scores=new int[5];
        String[] dates=new String[5];

for (int i=1;i<=4;i++){//test data
            scores[i]=20+i;
            dates[i]="01/"+i+"/2017";
        }

        BowlingSystem a01=new BowlingSystem("a",dates,scores);
        a01.register(a01);

        for (int i=1;i<=4;i++){//test data
            scores[i]=30+i;
            dates[i]="02/"+i+"/2017";
        }

        BowlingSystem b01=new BowlingSystem("b",dates,scores);
        b01.register(b01);

        for (int i=1;i<=4;i++){//test data
            scores[i]=40+i;
            dates[i]="03/"+i+"/2017";
        }
        BowlingSystem c01=new BowlingSystem("c",dates,scores);
        c01.register(c01);

        for (int i=1;i<=4;i++){//test data
            scores[i]=20+i;
            dates[i]="05/"+i+"/2017";
        }

        BowlingSystem d01=new BowlingSystem("d",dates,scores);
        d01.register(d01);
        a01.out("a");//the outcome of this now is same as key "d"
        b01.out("b");//the outcome of this now is same as key "d"
        System.out.println("Please type in the name, in this case name is just a letter in lower case from a to d.\n");//below this line is not important
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 1);
        String name=stdin.readLine(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn about Java naming conventions. variables should start with a lower case character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `BowlingSystem` instances (the values of your `Map`) are referencing to the same arrays passed to their constructors (`dates` and `scores`), so modifying the content of the arrays affect all of them.

To avoid that, either your `BowlingSystem` should make a copy of the arrays passed to it, or you should pass different arrays to each instance you are creating.

For example,

replace

```
BowlingSystem a01=new BowlingSystem("a",dates,scores);
```

with

```
BowlingSystem a01=new BowlingSystem("a",new String[5],new int[5]);
```

and do the same for each of the constructor calls.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask you one more question? If I let Array A=Array B, then actually both A and B are referring to the same array. But if I use System.arraycopy then they are two different arrays with same content. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `dates` and `scores` are the same for all the keys in your HashMap. That's why when you print out the data, the last added data to the `dates` and `scores` are shown.